# How to use "ip link add" on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ip

I am new to Ubuntu network administration.

Can someone tell me what the command `ip link add` does?

I tried to google it, and I can't find any useful examples.

Comment: This command will create a virtual link. It accepts many options, thus answer could be quite extensive. May be you can narrow down your question? Also, take a look at this [man page](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=ip-link).

Comment: I am learning virtualization from some opensource code. The code will execute "IP link add" command to the tap interface. I would like to know how it works.